# CSS: give the same width to the text and password inputs

Tags: css, input, css-selectors

i'm trying to give the same width to the text and password inputs.

So i write this:

```
input[type="text","password"]{

    width: 138px;

}
```

But it doesn't work.

Any help?

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 16, accepted):

How about:

```
input[type="text"], input[type="password"]
{
    width: 138px;
}
```

or you use classes/ids:

```
input.text, input.password
{
    width: 138px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

How about?

```
input[type="text"],
input[type="password"]{
  width: 138px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
input[type="text"], input[type="password"]
```